# Given set is open or closed.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $O_n=(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) ,n=1,2,3,... $

Then

1.$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) =?$

2.$\cap_{n=1}^{\infty}(\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}) $ is closed or open ?

Comment: What have you tried? What tools do you know? Think very carefully about what $O_1 \cap O_2$ looks like? then what about $O_1 \cap O_2 \cap O_3$, and what pattern emerges, (also although i know you're probably using the 2-norm for your topology, but if one were pedantic, one would need to  say "open or closed wrt some topology")

Comment: What point is in all sets of the form $(-\frac{1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$? Can there be others?

Comment: I get {0} for intersection but i am not sure

Comment: What are you unsure about?

Comment: I am just draw the intervals from that i get {0} is that right ?every non empty finite set is not open and every finite set is close set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assert that the intersection is $\{ 0 \}$. If $x > 0$ with $x \in \cap_{n}(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$, then there is some $n > 1/x$ ensuring $1/n < x$, a contradiction; if $x < 0$ with $x \in \cap_{n}(\frac{-1}{n}, \frac{1}{n})$, then again there is some $n > 1/|x|$ ensuring $|x| > 1/n$, implying that $x < -1/n$, a contradiction. Note that $1/n \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$; we are done.

The set $\{ 0 \}$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}$ (if you cannot see this for now try to exert a little bit efforts to prove it) with respect to the usual topology.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

If $x \ne 0$, you could always find an $n$ such that $x \notin (-1/n, 1/n)$

Once you get answer for question 1, question 2 is obvious.